# how can i create Wordpress post with html body content using java

Tags: java, html, wordpress, image

I'm trying to post to my wordpress site programatically using java code with  XmlRpcClient api. I'm able to post a simple content but stuck with few things -

1. The post body - not able to format it with different size, font, etc. If i send as html, the post just shows as html code and does not resolve that to actaul formatted text.
2. Not able to add image to the post.

Any pointers to resolve above issue would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some code or how you call the api?

Comment: XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
        client.setConfig(config);
        
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Hashtable post = new Hashtable();
        post.put("post_title", title);
        post.put("post_content", body);
        post.put("post_status", "publish");

Comment: Hashtable taxonomies = new Hashtable();
taxonomies.put("category", categories);
taxonomies.put("post_tag", tags);

Comment: String postId = (String) client.execute("wp.newPost", params);

Comment: No one tried automating wordpress posts ??